# wordcloud for non-english corpus

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, nlp, jupyter-notebook, word-cloud

[wordcloud for non English text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdUCc.png)

Dear friends
I am facing problems in generating proper wordcloud for non english text. The cloud is generated but it gives un-satisfactroy results. It shows wordcloud with characters only while I require wordcloud with proper words.
I processed following code to generate wordcloud.

```
from os import path
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import unicodedata
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
text = scorpus
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='MBKhursheed.ttf',
                      relative_scaling = 1.0,
                      stopwords = sw
                      ).generate(text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is `wordcloud` https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud? Maybe this will help: https://github.com/alvations/translation-cloud . Putting the font inside the directory helped for me when printing out chinese/japanese.

Comment: No one is there to satisfy my problem????????????????

Comment: Here's some help: bounty.

Comment: Give an example of the corpus your using

Comment: Can you give example of corpus and current output?

Comment: arabic I think judging by the font

Answer (score 4):

first you need to import (possibly install first) these two:

```
from arabic_reshaper import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
```

then use it as the following:

```
text = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(text))
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='MBKhursheed.ttf',
                      relative_scaling = 1.0,
                      stopwords = sw
                      ).generate(text)
```